# Which one I have to follow for W3 Validation?

Tags: html, css, validation

In W3 validations it have many options

HTML - XHTML1.0, XHTML - Transitional, XHTML - Strict and

for CSS - CSS - 2.0, CSS - 3.0 ...

Which one I should follow? Any suggestion plz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Validate as whichever you've targeted your document to. If you're producing HTML, validate as that. Likewise, if you're writing XHTML, validate as that. Go read the w3 docs on each spec to decide which you want to follow.

Answer (score 1):

HTML5, HTML4 Strict or, if you have to, XHTML1 Strict. Don't fall into the trap of Transitional versions for new sites, you'll regret it later.

I'd use CSS3, but CSS2.1 is alright as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'd personally say:

> HTML 4.01 Strict
>   CSS 2.1

This is because I (and many others) feel XHTML is flawwed which is why W3C is stopping development of the XHTML2 stanrd in favor of HTML5 (which you won't be using in another couple of years because of lack in browser support)

Also another problem of XHTML is that it should be send with a MIME type of application/xhtml+xml however internet explorer 6 (maybe 7 and 8 too, not sure) do not render the page when it send as application/xhtml+xml, so you'll either need to send text/html for ie and text/html+xml for other browser, or use the wrong mime type completely.

http://www.w3.org/News/2009#item119 - W3C stops development of XHTML2

http://hixie.ch/advocacy/xhtml - Lengthy article about XHTML by Ian Hickson (creator of Acid2 and Acid3 test and member of WHATWG)

Answer (score 0):

css 2.x is used in 99% cases

Do yiu know what **DOCTYPE** is? HTML and XHTML are different languages. If m then it's XHTML.

I make things tooooo simple. Better browse the web